# Installation problem, not showing partitions

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

When it comes into installing Ubuntu I really wanted to try and not break anything.

I have Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS on a bootable USB and set my BIOS to make it the priority boot device, which worked great, so I'm running Ubuntu through the USB.

Then clicking the icon to install, made sure my WIFI is connected to the internet and it will install updates while installing. It will add the 3rd party software.

I click continue and then get a screen I wasn't expecting. Here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-long-term-support at step 4 it shows clear options for installation of the partitions I'm not getting that. I get this:

[image]

I'm trying to make the laptop a dual boot between Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04

Specifications:

- Sony Vaio
- Intel i3-2367m @1.4GHz
- 8GB DDR3
- 500gb HHD

Answer (score -1):

You  should have two choices...install and keep present OS, or Install Ubuntu ie ( format and wipe windows and install Ubuntu as only OS....I did not install from usb, I downloaded and installed from cd-rom, so I don't know if there is a difference.